# How can I figure out when a user is watching both a movie and another movie's credits?

Tags: sql, datetime, time, concurrency, hiveql

I have a table that looks like `(user_id, movie_id, start_timestamp, end_timestamp, reason_for_end)`. Movies can either end because the user turns them off (`reason_for_end == 'user_initiated'`) or because the credits finish (`reason_for_end == 'inactivity'`). The credits always last exactly two hours.

I want to know the total number of times that a user started a new movie while another movie was in the credits phase.

Separately, I also want to know the total amount of time that a user spends watching a movie while the credits of another movie are still rolling.

EDIT:
Example given table:

```
user_id   movie_id   start_timestamp        end_timestamp          reason_for_end
1         1          2012-11-18 05:53:36.0  2012-11-18 12:46:40.0  'inactivity'
1         2          2012-11-18 11:34:23.0  2012-12-18 13:21:57.0  'user_initiated'
```

Example result table 1:

```
user_id   times_new_started_while_old_in_credits
1         1
```

Example result table 2:

```
user_id   total_overlap_in_seconds
1         4320
```

Comment: seems like you just need to setup the correct SELF JOIN, or WHERE IN or WHERE EXISTS subselect statements.  But your question isn't totally clear perhaps you could provide some sample data and a desired result based up on that sample that will help us understand the logic that would be needed. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Comment: just coming back, the update to the question was good looks like Robert has provided something to you that hopefully will put you on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that?

You should tweak date-time handling to your target database syntax. Also, I do not know how you wish to handle situations when user jumps between more films simultaneously - that's up to you ;-)

Otherwise, this should do the job:

```
SELECT movie1.user_id, count(*), sum(movie1.end_timestamp - movie2.start_timestamp)
FROM movies movie1
LEFT JOIN movies movie2
    ON movie1.user_id = movie2.user_id
    AND movie1.reason_for_end = 'inactivity'
WHERE movie2.start_timestamp BETWEEN movie1.end_timestamp - '2hours'::interval AND movie1.end_timestamp
    AND movie1.user_id = 1 /* optional */
GROUP BY movie1.user_id
```

Comment: you can probably take out the AND movie1.id < movie2.id while it is likely true we don't know how the identifiers are handled yet.

Comment: Will check if that will work asap. ON a side note, what do you mean about tweaking the date-time handling?

Comment: _movie1.end_timestamp - '2hours'::interval_ is PostgreSQL-specific syntax. You might have to change it a little.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. There should be another AND statement in the LEFT JOIN clause to take into account that movie1 must have ended because of inactivity, right?